# Is there a easy way to detect the use of jni in a android app?

Tags: android, android-ndk

On Android SDK >=9 there is a `ApplicationInfo` field that points to the `nativeLibraryDir`.

I was wondering if there is something similar for android SDK <9?

Or, if someone knows if that exists: a field somewhere that indicates that a package is using native libraries?

Answer (score 0):

How about the [sharedLibraryFiles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#sharedLibraryFiles) field? Wouldn’t that indicate the presence of native code?

Comment: Interesting, will check it out.